# How to mock non class member function using sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

i need to add mock to the method2 function. but i am getting error

> "TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property method2 as function"

```
class ServiceClass {

  async method1() {

  }

}

async function method2() {}

module.exports = ServiceClass;
```

Comment: have you tried exporting the function? as of now, you're only exporting the ServiceClass, so method2 won't be accessible from the outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside method2 i was calling another method3. i added mock to that. Unfortunately exporting the method2 didn't give the expected output.

```
async function method2{
 method3();
}

method3(){
 //wrote mock here and it worked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to export your async method2

```
// my-module.es6

export default class ServiceClass {

  async method1() {

  }

}

export async function method2() {}

// test.js

import { method2 } from 'my-module';

const spy = sinon.spy(method2);
```

However, its not clear if you intended method2 to be in your class?  If that was the case, you would do the same thing as method1 and do something like this

```
// test.js

import ServiceClass from 'my-module';

const serviceClass = new ServiceClass();

const spy = sinon.spy(serviceClass, 'method2');
```

Comment: sinon stub was not accepting even if you export the method. But i was using some other library method in method2. I mocked that library and got the expected output. Thank you for your time.